# Converting object to union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a question for typescript. I want to create somemething like union from a object values. How I can achieve this? 
eg:

```
const x = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 'a string',
    k: document.createElement('div')
}

const y = (y: the value which exist of x ): boolean => {
  return true
}
```

Something like:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```

but for objects. 
Any hints are welcome.

Comment: `ValueOf<typeof x>`?

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir thanks for  your comment. But if I try this I still can use y('test') which must not be possible. If argument is a string only 'a string' must be allowed.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment ...`ValueOf<typeof x>` will be a union of all values in the type of `x`.  this appears tp be `number | string | HTMLElement` for the x you have defined  or do you want literal types (ie `1` | 2` | `a string ` | HTMlElement`)

Comment: @Titian  Cernicova-Dragomir Exactly. But I want behaviour similar like if I write const y = (y: 1 | 2 | 'a string') ... in this case passing 'test' as an argument will not be possible

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get a union of the values in the type of a variable you can use `ValueOf<typeof x>`. For your example that type would be `string | number | HTMLDivElement`

```
const x = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 'a string',
    k: document.createElement('div')
}
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]; 
const y = (P: ValueOf<typeof x>): boolean => { // p:  string | number | HTMLDivElement
   return true
}
```

From the comments you want the literal types (`1 | 2 | "a string"`) not the base types. For this to work, you need to change the type pf `x` to include the literal types. The simplest way to do this is in 3.4 to add a `const` assertion:

```
const x = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 'a string',
    k: document.createElement('div')
} as const
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
const y = (p: ValueOf<typeof x>): boolean => { // p:  1 | 2 | "a string" | HTMLDivElement
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you need:

```
export const xx = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 'a string',
    k: document.createElement('div')
};

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type XValues = ValueOf<typeof xx>;
```